Setting up ContextProvider with Expo Stack
I have a RootStack that I'm trying to wrap so I have access to my user object(s) and it's not updating like it did when I had it bare. Is this wrong?
main _layout file

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Slot, Stack } from 'expo-router';
import 'react-native-reanimated';
import AuthContextProvider from '@/contexts/AuthContext';

import AppWrapper from '@/components/layout/AppWrapper';

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <AppWrapper>
        <Slot />
      </AppWrapper>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}


My wrapper:
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, SplashScreen, Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { DefaultTheme, DefaultDarkTheme } from '@/styles/theme';

import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';
import { colors } from '@/styles/colorPalette';

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

export default function AppWrapper({children}: {children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[]}) {
  const darkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const loaded = useAuth().loaded
  const user = useAuth().user

  console.log("user object in wrapper is: ", user)

  if (!!loaded) {
    SplashScreen.hideAsync()
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider
      value={darkMode ? DefaultDarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
    >
      { loaded ?
        <Stack
          screenOptions={{
            contentStyle: {
              backgroundColor: darkMode ? colors.background.darkBg : colors.background.lightBg
            },
            headerShown: false
          }}
        >
          { !!user ?
            <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
          :
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{animation: 'fade'}} />  
              <Stack.Screen name="redirect" options={{animation: 'fade'}}/>
            </>
          }
        </Stack>
      : null} 
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

